# SceneManager LoadScene is not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have simple button and on click i run function from my script. It goes well with main scene and mainScript and it directs it to Job scene, but then i created another jobScript that i use for job scene, i use the same function and it is not working.

Here is function:

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public void changeScene(string nextScene)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(nextScene);
}
```

I really do not know why it is no working. I checked if i entered scene name correctly, and i did. If need more material, please tell me and i will update post.

Comment: If you placed a breakpoint on SceneManager.LoadScene(nextScene);, is there anything null or empty? Does it even reach that breakpoint? Did you add the scene to your build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I set onClick to off so i changed to RuntimeOnly and it works. Thanks. I was looking for it half a day.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if you added the scene to the build

Comment: There are other answers (marked as answered) posted by OP himself, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer [see: How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure to give exact name of scene in inspector at OnClick() event.
2. In the script pass the right argument variable name i.e
   ChangeScene(string sceneName), sceneName is the right argument to pass in and as SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);